# Click disabled for some condition

Tags: angular

```
<div [ngClass]="{'seat-reserve' : isSpotSelected(i, j), 'seat-busy inner-busy' : spot === 1 }" 
     class="inner" 
     *ngFor="let spot of place; let j = index" 
     (click)="togglePlace(i, j)">
  <span [hidden]='isSpotSelected(i, j) || spot === 1' class="content">{{j+1}}</span>
</div>
```

It's poosible call click method only when spot !== 1, I wonder that call method whole times and return 0 when spot !== 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable click only on some condition, you could do something like this.

```
(click)="condition ? FunctionToBeExecuted : false"
```